# accessing to element id attribute value inside jquery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm selecting html elements

```
var elements = $('*[my-elem="false"]');
```

since each element has attribute id with some value I want inside iteration to get id of currently iterated element, so I tried

```
$.each(elements, function(index, item){
    var itemId = item.attr("id").val();        
});
```

but I'm getting following error

```
TypeError: item.attr is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `console.log(item)`. You should see that it's a regular HTML element -- not a jQuery object.

Note that `.val()` refers specifically to the `value` attribute of an element.

Both of those in mind, if your goal is to get the ID, you can use `item.id`, `this.id`, or `$(item).attr("id")`.

Comment: You're welcome! If this is correct, please make sure to click the checkmark to show this is the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

[.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery method, so you need to use your element as if it were a jQuery selector. Also, you don't need `.val` for `.attr('id')`, so this should work

```
var itemId = $(item).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

it is as simple as

```
var itemId = item.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` is a DOM element, `attr` is a jQuery function, so you just have to wrap it in the jQuery notation `var itemId = $(item).attr('id').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of **each** when looping over DOM elements. Use this one. (https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
elements.each(function(index){
  var itemId = $(this).attr('id').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elements = $('selector');
elements.each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemId = this.id;
```

will also work

Comment: You mean `this.id`, right? Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.